# JSON returned from ASP.NET not usable in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I'm returning a DataSet converted to JSON via a jQuery AJAX call, all is well! The request I receive back is:

```
{"Table":[[2,"BlackBerry Tour","2013-09-10","2013-09-13","Project"],null]}
```

Looks valid to me, also ran it through JSLint validator, again, all is well! Now, whenever I try to access any of this data, I simply receive undefined from the following:

```
var dataObject = data.d //data.d is the response from the server and what is logged above
console.log(dataObject.Table) //undefined
console.log(dataObject["Table"]) //undefined
```

Now, if I run `JSON.parse(dataObject)`, I can then access it alright. This is a problem right now however, since the site this will reside on sticks IE into IE7 mode, and `JSON` is always undefined according to IE (I know, IE7, it's out of my hands tho).

So my question is **why can I not use the returned JSON as is? why must I run it through JSON.parse before using it?** More info is available on request (AJAX call, DataSet converter, etc)

AJAX Call, per request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DBManager.asmx/GetAdminList",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '{"strEmail": "' + strFilter + '" }',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d); //valid JSON response.
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting back *string* `LOG: {"Table":[[2,"Bl....` ?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, LOG isn't part of that string

Comment: How do you call the web service in jQuery? Should be able to use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), which automatically parses the response and gives you a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Jan -- Ill post the AJAX call, one moment

Comment: OK, thats strange. I would assume, that you should get an object back, but data.d seems to be a string. Have you tried parsing it with [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). This sould be available in IE7.

Comment: What is the return type of DBManager.GetAdminList? I'm guessing it's `string` since `DataSet` doesn't JSON serialize particularly well.

Comment: @Snixtor -- Yup, it was a String, I had a fantastic time fiddling with that damn `JavaScriptSerializer` earlier today...not fun :\

Comment: I'm not sure how to customize serialization from ASP.NET page methods (I've only done it in Web API), but you'd keep things simpler if you had `GetAdminList` return a strongly typed complex object instead of the JSON string. Instead of pouring your effort into JSON serialization (which I acknowledge you've already done), how about converting the `DataSet` into a simpler object representation which the default serializer can manage?

Comment: An applicable resource about what's going on here with "double serialization" - http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you returning back a *string* you have to somehow parse it into an object. E.g.

```
var data = '{"Table":[[2,"BlackBerry Tour","2013-09-10","2013-09-13","Project"],null]}';

var dataJ
eval('dataJ = ' + data )

alert(dataJ.Table)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvvAm/

If you're using jQuery you can use

```
var dataJ = $.parseJSON(data);
```

This is preferable, since `eval` is open to all kinds of attacks.

Comment: Ahh...ahhhhh! Makes sense...probably should've caught that. Since `JSON` always give undefined through IE, is `eval` looking like my best bet (no third-party plugins)?

Comment: Since you already using jQuery, you can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON, I think it's preferavle to eval

Comment: Thanks for saving me some headaches man, appreciate it, I would change the answer to use `$.parseJSON`, I'm staying away from `eval` :D

Comment: Me too, that was just the proof of concept, will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataObject = eval('(' + data + ')');

alert(dataObject.Table);
```

Try this thing may help you.

Comment: Returns `undefined` :\